# registerForRemoteNotifications() blocks mainthread when called from testflight

Tags: ios, push-notification, testflight, appdelegate

I have a weird bug in my iOS-app. First of all: the bug only appears using Testflight, not when compiling the app through xCode and running it on a device.

I have a simple onboarding `TabView` with three tabs. The first one has a button where the user can allow notifications:

```
@EnvironmentObject var delegate: AppDelegate
//some Code
Button("allow notifications") {
    delegate.registerForPushNotifications()
}
```

If I use this button, the bug does not appear. Not in xCode nor in Testflight. But if the user doesn't use the button, I ask for permission for notifications when the first tab disapears:

```
.onDisappear {
    if page.id == 0 { //page.id is the current tab
        delegate.registerForPushNotifications()
    }
}
```

And now it get's weird: when I don't allow notifications using this `onDisappear`-function, the whole app freezes and becomes unresponsive. I can't swipe anymore to change the tabs. When I bring the app in the background it takes a while and it crashes due to a watchdog termination with the error code `0x8badf00d` - [ate bad food](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations). This means the app took to long to terminate (yes, because it got unresponsive).

To summarize:

- xCode using button: allow/deny notifications → OK
- xCode using onDisappear: allow/deny → OK
- Testflight using button: allow/deny → OK
- Testflight using onDisappear: allow → OK | deny → unresponsive

My guess is that inside the `registerForPushNotifications()` function the mainthread gets blocked. So here comes the code for that:

```
//some code with struct xxx: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var delegate: AppDelegate
//some code with OnboardingView().environmentObject(delegate) }

class AppDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
//some code

    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("D'oh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                guard granted else {
                    //permission denied
                    return
                }
                //permission granted
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But the `DispatchQueue.main.async` isn't called when the user denies notifications, right? Has it something to do with production and sandbox environments? But why does it work when the button is pressed?

I'm thankful for every answer, as this problem is not easy to debug because I have to upload a new build to Testflight everytime. If it's needed I can send an invite-link for the beta inside Testflight. The bug happens right after the first onboarding screen.

Comment: Start by running a release build from Xcode instead of a debug build to see if it is release optimisations that are messing you up. Second, presenting a dialog from `onDisappear` sounds potentially problematic to me; you could be getting stuck in the view hierarchy changing. Perhaps dispatch async the call to `registerForPushNotifications` in the `onDisappear`

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your fast reply. I ran a release build from Xcode and I did not get the error this time. I tried to dispatch the `registerForPushNotifications` call using ```.onDisappear { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1, execute: { delegate.registerForPushNotifications() })}``` but the bug keeps happening. I have found a workaround with your tip: I attach `registerForPushNotifications()` to the second actual button of the onboarding: the one that ends the onboarding. Not quite what I wanted but okay.